# jQuery: Toggle not Toggling

Tags: jquery, gallery

I'm currently building the Full Throttle WP Theme and I've come to a dead end. I'm trying to make it so when you click the Thumbnail at the top it will then load into the large background. Before I added some jQuery effects to the toggle and images it worked fine and still works fine if I remove the jQuery coding. Would it be possible for anyone to have a quick look and see if I'm doing something wrong.

There are two jQuery script files. Global:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {

    $(".dropgallery a, #fp_thumbtoggle").removeAttr("title");

    $('#fp_thumbtoggle, .dropgallery img').click(function() {
        $('#fp_thumbtoggle').toggleClass("active");

        if ($('#fp_thumbtoggle').hasClass('active')){
            $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'65px'});
        }else{
            $('#fp_thumbtoggle').animate({top:'185px'});
        }
        $('.dropgallery').slideToggle('500');
        return false;
    });

    });
```

and [Gallery](http://www.media21a.co.uk/development/fullthrottle/wp-content/themes/fullthrottle/js/gallery.js).

Like I said, if I remove the Global script it works fine but I'll lose all the jQuery toggle effects.

Once again thank you for any advice and help. I know the images load slowly; I just need to tweak the sizes.

Comment: Works fine for me, I think. I'm running Chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

can you try removing `return false;`. this may blocking the thumbnail click event.